# Convert From Decimal to BigInt (6 character precision)

Tags: c#, postgresql, decimal, npgsql, bigint

I am consuming a web service in C# and inserting the records into a postgres database via the Npgsql library.

I have a cost field that the web service gives me as a decimal type "12.57"
my postgres database and application expect it to be a fixed 6 digit number of a BigInt type like "125700"

I cannot think of a great way to do this other than something like convert it to a string, remove the decimal pad a few 0's and convert to an Int64.

Am I missing a simpler way?

Edit: I should add that currently I use an Npgsql parameter type of BigInt and when I feed it the cost, it is just rounding 12.57 to 13 in the database

Comment: It rounds because bigint is an int.  It doesnt handle decimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just multiply by 10000?

Comment: I will look at some more sample prices to see if this will work in all cases, but a great idea if so

Comment: After looking through a bunch of my sample costs, this seems to be working in every scenario. My application expects 4 digit precision but I cannot find a single cost that goes beyond 2 digits. Multiplying by 10000 keeps my 2 from the cost and pads the extra 2 for the application. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preserve the cost values with 2 digits after the decimal point, multiply the value by 100 before storing it in the database.

```
string cost = "12.57";
decimal d = decimal.Parse(cost);
if (d >= 10000.0m)
{
    throw new Exception("Input value " + cost + " is too large");
}
int i = (int)(d * 100.0m + 0.5m);
string result = i.ToString();
```

The `+ 0.5m` will round the value in case there are more than 2 digits after the decimal point.